# How to move statefulset pod to another node?

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-statefulset

Due to the following error, my `MySQL` statefulset pod cannot be run on the particular node.

```
EXT4-fs error (device sdb): __ext4_find_entry:1532: inode #2: comm mysqld: reading directory lblock 0
```

The issue is described with the details here:

[GKE Kubernetes MySQL Input/output error Ext4Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71014411/gke-kubernetes-mysql-input-output-error-ext4error)

I would like to move the statefulset pod to the different node. How to do that?

Comment: Is there a reason not to remove the problematic node from service so that the statefulset pods would be scheduled elsewhere? [This guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/safely-drain-node/) describes how to drain a node and then the node itself can be shutdown without disruption to workload.

Comment: Please ask infrastructure related questions on the dedicated serverfault sister site of SO, not on the programming focused SO.